# present perfect continuous and repetition

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a previous post I asked if "websites i have been visiting today" means that I have visited the same sites multiple times and the answer was "yes".

If I say: "I don't want people to know what websites I have been visiting" does the same principle apply  (I have visited the same sites repeatedly) or does it mean "various websites I have visited recently/lately", so not necessarily the same sites over and over again?

Comment: It doesn't imply the same websites

Comment: @Colin Fine Does "websites I have been visiting today" imply the same websites in your opinion?

Comment: @anouk No, it doesn't imply the same website. It means several different websites, it can also a particular website visited multiple times along with others.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh Is this an answer to my original question or my question for Colin Fine?

Comment: @anouk Aren't both of them nearly same? To simply say, both cases would never inflict the idea that the same website is visited over and over again. It may have been so, but if you are visiting even one other site other than the repetitive one, it would fit this sentence. If you want to speak about a single website that you have been visiting the whole day, use something like: _I don't want people to know about the website I have been visiting today._

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh I am not talking about one site, I mean several sites. So in your opinion "websites I have been visiting today" could mean several different websites I have visited only once?

Comment: @anouk Yes, once, twice, thrice, n-number of visits.

Comment: @anouk: To my ear, _websites I have been visiting today_ does not _imply_ that I have visited some of them several times, but it does suggest that interpretation. It suggests it more strongly over a shorter period of time, such as a day; but it is still only a suggestion.